# Speed of sound at a specific air temperature

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, acoustics, speed

What is the speed of sound in air at 140°F?

Comment: What accuracy do you need? Depending on that, relative humidity may play some role.

Comment: If air temperature reaches $140^o$ F then the speed of sound is the very least of your worries.

Answer (score 3):

you have to convert °F to °K or °C than look up the formula for sound speed in wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound#Speed_of_sound_in_ideal_gases_and_air